# Jquery isotope filtering mechanism not working, instead page just refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, templates, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to use Isotope for a filtering mechanism in my Rails application.

I have included in a JS file I send to the client:

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  ISOTOPE PORTFOLIO
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $container = $('.items');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows'
        });
    });

    $('.portfolio .filter li a').click(function () {

        $('.portfolio .filter li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

as for my HTML:

```
<div class="portfolio">
      <ul class="filter">
        <li><a class="active" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".vegan">Vegan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".organic">Organic</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="items col4">
            <li class="item vegan">
              <figure class="icon-overlay medium icn-more">
                <a href="" class="fancybox-media" data-rel="portfolio">
                  <img src="default.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </figure>
              <div class="image-caption">
                <h3><a href="#">How to cook quinoa</a></h3>
                <span class="meta"></span>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item organic">
              <figure class="icon-overlay medium icn-more">
                <a href="" class="fancybox-media" data-rel="portfolio">
                  <img src="default.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </figure>
              <div class="image-caption">
                <h3><a href="#">How to organic food</a></h3>
                <span class="meta"></span>
              </div>
            </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

When I click on a filter button, all it does is refresh the webpage.

Additionally, I send over to the client jquery.isotope.min.js which should be the source for isotope to work.

This code came as part of a theme used for the Rails application.

There are no console errors indicating a problem with isotope.

EDIT:

The code is working fine, but is not being executed in the browser after placing a breakpoint on the JS function.

Also, I notice the template and my rails app is using jquery.isotope.min.js, where as the fiddle is using isotope.pkgd.min.js

The template can be found at:

http://themeforest.net/item/-slowave-multipurpose-responsive-wordpress-theme/6870792

Comment: Your code is working just fine, check this *[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmarwen/qp1h7rz8/)*.

Comment: Then what's going on? This is in a rails application, and everytime I select a filter it refreshes the page. Each filter button becomes a link to http://localhost:3000/#

Comment: The issue is that the code is not being executed whatsoever. I have a breakpoint on the JS in the browser and it doesn't stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: @tmarwen made http://jsfiddle.net/tmarwen/qp1h7rz8/ which works perfectly fine. The issue is it's not being executed for some reason.

Comment: Additionally, I have a breakpoint elsewhere in the same file that the isotope JS is located in, and it stops there. So for some reason this specific function is not being found/called.

Comment: So the JS is loaded in client side but not executed? Quite strange...

Comment: Have you any way to post a real page where we can see it failing?

Comment: Unfortunately not at this time. I could push it to a heroku app but then rails would detect production mode and obfuscate the JS. This originated from this http://themeforest.net/item/-slowave-multipurpose-responsive-wordpress-theme/6870792 template. I suspect the issue isn't with that template since the jsfiddle of my code works perfect, but rather an asset issue with rails somehow? Please let me know if you can think of a way to provide working example, I'll be back online later this afternoon.

Comment: The template uses isotope v1.5 and the fiddle uses isotope v2. This may be one reason for the fiddle working and the code not.

Comment: The filter mechanism works fine in the templates html file, however in my rails app it does not. Where on the template page does it say the isotope version?

Comment: Also, I notice the template and my rails app is using jquery.isotope.min.js, where as the fiddle is using isotope.pkgd.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be an error in another piece of javascript that was loaded before the isotope JS was able to execute. Removing/resolving the broken JS fixed the issue.